# dspic33fj128mc804 and eeprom 25LC256 by SPI

Tags: microcontroller, spi, microchip, eeprom

I am trying to write and read from the EEPROM (25LC256) with my dsPIC 33FJ128MC804, I tried to use the examples from the website, however they used the explorer16 with the dsPIC 33FJ256MC710, so I take the code and I made the changes to used it in my dsPIC but I started to use interruptions, right now I can send data, but I am not able to read from the memory, even if I follow the steps in the datasheet of the EEPROM and using the configuration of the SPI.

Could you help me please with this little problem please?

UPDATE: I just noticed that whenever I send the code for read the STATUS register I always get zero as answer, is it normal?

source code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wdahlmhjrilcqw6/main.c?dl=0

Comment: No we couldn't help you with this little problem. There is not enough information to do so. Clarify what you are asking and put the code in the question.

Comment: Other than being very careful with peripheral pin select and making absolutely sure that all other fixed functions on the relevant pins are disabled, it is a matter of reading and rereading the dataspec. Don't forget to have a look at the errata. Keep in mind that working code is not always correct code. (e.g. happens to work due coincidence). IIRC MCx10 had errata for SPIROV.

Comment: Hi, have you fixed your problem ? I'm having the same issue
Thanks